# What are the applications of Belief Revision?

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, propositional-logic, theory, knowledge-representation

In my Computer Science graduation, I came across this concept of Belief Revision, which focus on knowledge representation and the possible operations that can be done with the facts that a "rational agent" knows.

I'd like to know what are the applications of that field in real life and some examples of software being used nowadays that mainly utilize Belief Revision as a way to function and solve problems.

Comment: Where have you tried to find such examples? Perhaps you could get your hands on a copy of [JY Halpern's _Reasoning about Uncertainty_](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262533805/reasoning-about-uncertainty/) (either edition should do) to see the concept of belief revision in context.